# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool

Tags: eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I am tring to configure a dynamic web project using eclipse helos. I use tomcat 6. When I add the libraries to the WebContent/lib it works fine. But I want to a folder called lib in the project's root level(root/lib). When I put my library files to that folder it builds fine. Run fine to the login page. When I try to log in it gives
 "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool"
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a web app and deploying it as a WAR file in a Java EE container.  That means that your deployment must follow the WAR standards.  Put your JARs in WEB-INF/lib.  The container will find them there.

Tomcat 6 and 7 have changed things up so JDBC driver JARs need to go in the server /lib directory.  The app server expects to find them with its class loader.  Try putting the MySQL JDBC connector JAR in /lib and see if that helps.

Comment: the same error can come from: commons-pool or/and a Db connector (ie. mysql-connector-java) dependency missing. see http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/200302.mbox/%3C3E5F8902.8000805@pacageek.org%3E